# ¿Es posible agregar vuetify a un proyecto de vue ya creado?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify, frontend

necesito agregar vuetify para crear interfaz de usuario a una aplicacion creada en vue. Quiero saber si es posible agregar vuetify en este proyecto o si es necesario crearlo desde cero.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La respuesta, estrictamente hablando es: **Sí es posible**. Si tienes el tiempo y los recursos, todo es posible. Pero, ¿por qué preguntas? ¿Ya lo intentaste? ¿Tuviste problemas? ¿Qué has hecho? ¿Qué has investigado?

Comment: Mi problema es que no encuentro información para hacerlo. Todo lo que encontré es para crear el proyecto desde cero.

Comment: Pues, la [documentación oficial](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#existing-applications) muestra una forma de añadir vuetify a un proyecto existente. Ya lo intentaste?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, solo tienes que agregarlo al proyecto:

Instalarlo,

```
 npm install vuetify --sav
```

agregarlo

```
vue add vuetify
```

y usarlo

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

> Recomiendo backup antes de todo.